# I keep getting a space in my program from cin.get()

Tags: terminal, compilation, c++

This is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

#define RAND(a,b) (a + rand()% (b-a+1))


int main()
{
    int num; 
    int computer_total = 0, players_total = 0;
    string name;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(;;)
    {
        cout <<"What's your name? ";
        cin >> name;
        cin.get();
        if(name == "stop")exit(0);

        for(int i =0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cout << name <<" roll the dice.\n";
            cin.get();                         //skips the cin.get() the first time aroun
            num = RAND(1,6);                   //Also makes akward spacing 
            players_total += num;
            cout <<"You got: " << num << endl;

            cout <<"Now it's the computers turn.\n";
            cin.get();
            num = RAND(1,6); 
            computer_total += num;
            cout <<"Computer got: " << num << endl;
        }

        cout <<"Total of computers dice: " << computer_total << endl;
        cout <<"Total of your dice: " << players_total << endl;

        if(computer_total == players_total)cout <<"Its a tie! \n"; 
        else if(computer_total > players_total)cout <<"Computer won.\n"; 
        else if(computer_total < players_total)cout <<"You won!\n";  
        //Do I need an else here?

    }

    return(0);
}
```

Where ever I use `cin.get()` I get awkward spacing when I compile the program. Like this:

[image]

Yet I need to use `cin.get()` to allow the user to roll the dice for himself/herself and the computer. Not sure if I'm using it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you press enter then it stays there printed (that's where this line comes from). Use some no-echoing function, ncurses got it.
Oh and about skipping first input, use cin.ignore() right before your get.

> //Do I need an else here?

Nah